# Какой падеж употребить после двоеточия? (тире или двоеточие?)

Tags: падежи, пунктуация

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно:

"Я видела красивую пару: изящная девушка лет двадцати и высокий мужчина лет тридцати"
или
"Я видела красивую пару: изящную девушку лет двадцати и высокого мужчину лет тридцати"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом предложении нужно поставить тире, так как ***распространённое приложение*** "изящную девушку лет двадцати и высокого мужчину лет тридцати" употреблено в конце предложения, имеет уточняющую, поясняющую информацию. Приложение употребляется в том же падеже, что и определяемое слово ПАРУ: ***"Я видела красивую пару - изящную девушку лет двадцати и высокого мужчину лет тридцати".***

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны варианты:

"Я видела красивую пару: изящную девушку лет двадцати и высокого мужчину лет тридцати"- однородные члены после обобщающего слова.

"Я видела красивую пару - изящную девушку лет двадцати и высокого мужчину лет тридцати".- может быть поставлено тире вместо двоеточия после обобщающего слова перед группой однородных членов, если однородные члены имеют характер приложения или уточнения:Сказки любят все – и взрослые, и дети.  [Употребление тире в простом и сложном предложении](http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37405.php)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.
Выходит, что вообще два варианта возможны? 
Я озадачена.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, по-моему, верен второй вариант, так как предложение простое. Однако в сложном предложении согласования, конечно нет (Я видела красивую пару: изящная девушка лет двадцати и высокий мужчина лет тридцати шли по набережной)

Comment: Спасибо за пример.

Но во втором предложении надо заменить двоеточие на тире, как мне объяснили в одной группе.

Comment: Я категорически против тире в данном случае! Вообще какое-либо явление можно описать или при помощи анализа, или при помощи синтеза. Двоеточие осуществляет анализ, то есть расчленяет предмет на несколько более доступных для понимания частей, либо указывает на основную, наиболее характерную часть. В вашем примере двоеточие раскрывает подробности о наблюдаемой паре. Тире, наоборот, предлагает мыслить о явлении как о целом, и поэтому характеризует его, сравнивая и часто противопоставляя явлениям внешним, существующим отдельно и независимо от первого.

Comment: Например, хоть это и менее красиво, но можно сказать и так: Изящная девушка лет двадцати и высокий мужчина шли по набережной - какая красивая пара!

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ.
Вот уж теперь совсем запуталась. Кто-то говорит, что двоеточие будет грубой ошибкой, кто-то говорит, что тире будет ошибкой. А я в полнейшем замешательстве.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, однородные члены должны согласоваться в падеже с обобщающими словами

Comment: Мне в одной группе девушка сказала, что слово "пара" вряд ли можно считать обобщающим при однородных членах. И стоит написать вот так: "Я видела красивую пару - изящную девушку лет двадцати и высокого мужчину лет тридцати".